# C language: change user input

Tags: c

I need to write program that get `Input` from user and in case i have `quate` (`"`) i need to change all the `chars` inside the `quotes` to `uppercase`.

```
int main()
{
    int quoteflag = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char str[127] = { '\0' };

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isdigit(ch))
    {
        ++i;
        if (ch == '"')
            quoteflag = !quoteflag;

        if (quoteflag == 0)
            str[i] = tolower(ch);
        else
        {
            strncat(str, &ch, 1);
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\"')
            {
                char c = toupper(ch);
                strncat(str, &c, 1);
            }

            strncat(str, &ch, 1);
            quoteflag = !quoteflag;
        }

        if (ch == '.')
        {
            strncat(str, &ch, 1);
            addnewline(str);
            addnewline(str);
        }
        else
        {
            if ((isupper(ch) && !quoteflag))
            {
                char c = tolower(ch);
                strncat(str, &c, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n-----------------------------");
    printf("\nYour output:\n%s", str);
    getchar();

    return 1;
}

void addnewline(char *c)
{
    char tmp[1] = { '\n' };
    strncat(c, tmp, 1);
}
```

So my problem here is in case my input is `"a"` this print at the end `"A` instead of `"A"` and i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `strncat` in a weird way.  First, `strncat` will always do nothing on big-endian systems.  What `strncat` does is read the inputs ... *as strings*.  So passing and `int` (four or eight bytes) into the function, it'll read the first byte.  If the first byte is `0`, then it'll believe it is the end of the string and will *not* add anything to *str*.  On little endian systems, the first byte should be the `char` you want, but on big-endian systems it will be the upper byte (which for an `int` that holds a value less than 255, will always be zero).  You can [read more about endianness here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

I don't know why you're using `strncat` for appending a single character, though.  You have the right idea with `str[i] = tolower(ch)`.  I changed `int ch` to `char ch` and then went through and replaced `strncat(...)` with `str[i++] = ...` in your code, and it compiled fine and returned the `"A"` output you wanted.  The source code for that is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int quoteflag = 0;
    char ch = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char str[127] = { '\0' };

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isdigit(ch))
    {
        if (ch == '"')
            quoteflag = !quoteflag;

        if (quoteflag == 0)
            str[i++] = tolower(ch);
        else
        {
            str[i++] = ch;
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\"')
            {
                char c = toupper(ch);
                str[i++] = c;
            }
            str[i++] = ch;
            quoteflag = !quoteflag;
        }

        if (ch == '.')
        {
             str[i++] = '.';
             str[i++] = '\n';
             str[i++] = '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            if ((isupper(ch) && !quoteflag))
            {
                char c = tolower(ch);
                str[i++] = c;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n-----------------------------");
    printf("\nYour output:\n%s", str);
    getchar();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `char ch = 0;` --> `int ch = 0;` would be better for `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && !isdigit(ch))`

Comment: @chux true for getchar(), as comparing a char to the int to `EOF` can cause problems, but isdigit() shouldn't be an issue.  Either way, there are more serious issues wiht this code (failing to check EOF on the inner while() loop, static initialization of `str` to 127 bytes with no input length checking, etc.  These are serious buffer overflow issues.  I get the sense OP is doing this as homework or tutorial, as s/he clearly isn't understanding some of these more important concepts. We were all there once, so helping OP to get the code *running* is the goal here.

Comment: In other words, I'd suggest OP start with input validation before worrying about edge-cases with `getchar()`, but yes, you are right that `int` is a better variable for `getchar()`

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the `++i;` line, then change:

```
str[i] = tolower(ch);
```

To:

```
str[i++] = tolower(ch);
```

Otherwise, since you pre-increment, if your first character is not a `"` but say `a`, your string will be `\0a\0\0...`. This leads us on to the next problem:

```
strncat(str, &ch, 1);
```

If the input is `a"`, then `strncat(str, &'"', 1);` will give a result of `\"\0\0...` as `strncat` will see `str` as an empty string. Replace all occurrences with the above:

```
str[i++] = toupper(ch);
```

(The `strncat()` may also be technically undefined behaviour as you are passing in an malformed string, but that's one for the language lawyers)

This will keep track of the index, otherwise once out of the quote loop, your first `str[i] = tolower(ch);` will start overwriting everything in quotes.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it by a few seconds! You're right about malformed strings, but look at my note on endianness - on big endian systems the first byte read by `strncat` will always be zero.  To use `strncat` in this way is not safe.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that it is `int ch`, so it's much worse than I thought!

Comment: @user979033 a string is just an array of characters. In c, a `char` is one byte, whereas an `int` is usually four bytes.  If you try to process an `int` like a string, it'll be a four-byte string, not a one-byte char.  As I mention in my answer, `strncat` only looks at the *first* byte of the int, not the whole value